# Calling header from JavaScript file

Tags: php, jquery

I want to display my theme's top menu/header in my single portfolio item pages. I'm thinking of a way to call `get_header()`, but as far as I understood I would have to do it in `scripts.js` (where the HTML that is supposed to be displayed just below the header is being built). I was able to display the theme's footer in the same pages by simply calling `get_footer()` on `content-sharing-portfolio.php`, but it seems that for the header it isn't so simple.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: The header typically contains everything in the `head` tag- styles, scripts, etc.. You can't just inject that into the middle of page.

Comment: *You could make your question simpler and deprived of unnecessary content so as to attract attention for possible assistance and answers! As it stands, it's not the case.*

Comment: @Milo, I was able to get what I want with the footer (calling it again on the portfolio item page, it just isn't visible in the 1st screenshot). I did it by simply calling `get_footer()` on `content-sharing-portfolio.php`. How can I achieve something similar with the header?

Comment: (@nyedidikeke indeed the question got long, what you think is dispensable? The screenshots, the code pieces? I thought they were being helpful in getting the context, what are your suggestions for removal?)

Comment: Keep it short and concise; it will make more sense than a plethora of words and or images. One significant question at a time, but not opinionated ones.

Comment: Done it, hope it helps.